# How to customize the stroke width of points in a googleVis for R chart?

Tags: r, google-visualization, bubble-chart, googlevis

I've [created a bubble chart](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9990581/geneCorrelations.html) using googleVis in R.

I really want to get rid of the grey stroke for the points because it looks ugly and where more points are clumped together it just forms an ugly set of lines.

I read in the User Guide that it is possible to customize this, but their instructions are for the Java version, and it doesn't seem to work with the R googleVis package.

Any ideas?

[image]

```
plot <- gvisBubbleChart(gene.correlations.sub, idvar="Gene", xvar="IPC_NonDividing", yvar="RG_NonDividing", sizevar="IPC_Dividing",
                        options=list(
                                width=1200, 
                                height=800,
                                sizeAxis="{minValue:0, maxvalue:1, minSize:3, maxSize:3}",
                                title="Gene Correlations with Ideal Non-Dividing IPC and RG Genes",
                                hAxis="{title:'Ideal IPC Gene Correlation'}", 
                                vAxis="{title:'Ideal RG Gene Correlation'}",
                                displayMode='markers',
                                colorAxis="{colors:['blue', 'white', 'red']}"

                        )
)

print(plot, file="geneCorrelations.html")
```